# How to automatically or programmatically add shared mailbox / shared folder to some user's Outlook for Web?

Tags: exchange, office365, outlook-web-access

I administer an Office 365 environment. This environment will contain a couple of shared mailboxes. I do not want my users to have to [manually add them to their Outlook for Web](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/add-a-shared-mailbox-to-outlook-on-the-web-98b5a90d-4e38-415d-a030-f09a4cd28207) when having to use them for the first time.

Instead, I would like to add the respective shared mailboxes automatically for them. Is there some option that allows me to do that for them? Or is there some PowerShell command that lets me do that?

Comment: Giving them full access to the mailbox doesn't automatically add the share mailbox to their outlook (via automapping)? With PowerShell `Add-MailboxPermission -Identity sharemailbox@contoso.onmicrosoft.com -User user@contoso.onmicrosoft.com -AccessRights FullAccess -AutoMapping:$true`, default should be AutoMapping:$true, but wrote it implicitly just to make usre.

Comment: It might do that with Microsoft Outlook (standalone). It does not do that with Outlook Online / Outlook for Web.

Comment: OWA definitely does not do that, if you want to access a shared mailbox on owa, you add the email address to the end of the url. For example https://outlook.office365.com/owa/sharemailbox@email.com.

Answer (score 0):

What about converting those to Office365 Groups and assign users as members.  That should auto-populate in Outlook for the web, as well as Outlook Mobile, and Outlook Desktop.